# NSUserDefaults not being saved - logic error?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

This is a strange error in my program which I think is a logical error on my part, or I'm misusing something.

Put concisely, when a value is entered into a NSTextField, it is not saved, but instead set as the placeholderValue of that TextField.  The second time the SavePreferences view is loaded, and the save function is ran, the value of the placeholderValue is written to NSUserDefaults.  I want to bypass that middle step, and just write the value of the NSTextField directly to NSUserDefaults the first time.

I am trying to save a value in `NSUserDefaults`.  What happens when the SavePreferences window is opened is the value is not saved, but rather set as the placeholder value.  When the preferences view is opened again, the placeholderString contains the value.  It is at this point when `btnSaveApiKey` is clicked (`.synchronize()` and/or `.setObject()`) that the placeholder value is written.

Am I calling some functions out of order, or should I add some functions to my SavePreferences class to handle some kind of Cocoa event that I am not aware of?

```
import Cocoa

class SavePreferences: NSViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var apiKeySavedText: NSTextField!
let userApiKeyConstant = "userApiKey"
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var apiKeyTitle = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userApiKey")

//MARK textfield for api key
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldApiKey: NSTextField!

//MARK save API Key as default preference

// SAVE FUNCTION
@IBAction func btnSaveApiKey(sender: AnyObject) {

    //save NSUserDefaults value
    defaults.setObject(self.textFieldApiKey.stringValue, forKey: userApiKeyConstant)

    // force save of NSUserDefaults with synchronize()
    defaults.synchronize()

    print("apikey saved as",  self.apiKeyTitle)
    apiKeySavedText.hidden = false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    apiKeySavedText.hidden = true
    if(self.defaults.valueForKey(userApiKeyConstant) != nil) {
        textFieldApiKey.placeholderString = self.defaults.stringForKey(userApiKeyConstant)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that use of synchronize is no longer necessary, and now discouraged by Apple. Nevertheless, I don't understand your question. Are you saying when `btnSaveApiKey` runs that the `NSUserDefaults` value is not being set?

Comment: Thanks Michael.  It is somehow being stored somewhere because when the view is loaded again, it appears in the placeholder text of the textbox. However it is not being stored in NSUserDefaults.  Only after it is set as the placeholder text does btnSaveApiKey write the value to NSUserDefaults.

Comment: But I don't understand what you're wanting. At the moment your reading NSUserDefaults and putting it into the placeholder, which I assume is working. Then you click the button and it writes the current text value (ie. not the placeholder) back to NSUserDefaults. If you launch again, the placeholder should show up with the value that you typed in and saved earlier. Is this what you want, and what part is not working? Or are you saying you can't find it in the NSUserDefaults location, in which case maybe you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: The part where current text value is supposed to be written to NSUserDefaults on the first click is not working.

Comment: So what result do you get from the `print` in `btnSaveApiKey`? And what is in `self.textFieldApiKey.stringValue` at that time?

Comment: It's different between the first time the view is loaded, and the subsequent times.  The first time it is whatever the previous value was.   The subsequent times, it is whatever value was intended to be saved the previous time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are confused because your save function does not print the saved string. This is because you declared apiKeyTitle once in the beginning. So, this is always what you saved earlier. To access the current value, change the following

```
print("apikey saved as",  self.apiKeyTitle)
```

to

```
print("apikey saved as ", defaults.stringForKey(userApiKeyConstant))
```

and remove the

```
var apiKeyTitle = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userApiKey")
```

variable, in case you don't need it somewhere else in your code.